# When does one use "nur zu Beginn" and when "erst zu Beginn"?

Tags: usage

One finds both "nur zu Beginn" and "erst zu Beginn" frequently in DWDS. In all cases it seems to tranlate to "only in/at the beginning". But it also appears as if there may be a nuance of usage in that, "erst zu Beginn" appears to be predominantly used with calendar time periods, whereas "nur zu Beginn" is used in reference to the starting point of events. Can anyone confirm, deny or elaborate?

Examples of [erst zu Beginn](https://bit.ly/40x3NYr) and examples of [nur zu Beginn](https://bit.ly/3K2KiRY).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nur" is generally "not at any other time", though if you're talking about the starting point of an event, it's clear that it's "not later". "Erst" specifically means "not earlier".

Comment: `though if you're talking about the starting point of an event, it's clear that it's "not later"` –– Can you give an example for that?

Comment: This explanation would be consistent with my initial suspicions. However, from DWDS:  Die Einschreibung ist bei uns nur zu Beginn des Jahres möglich. Translation: Enrollment is only possible at the beginning of the year. This implies that "enrollment begins, but is not necessarily limited to, the beginning of the year," does it not? That would be opposite of, "enrollment is not later than the beginning of the year." Nor is it the same as, "enrollment is not possible at any time other than the beginning of the year." So, there seems to be more to the usage.

Comment: @user52445 See the sentence in the other comment, for example: "nur zu Beginn des Jahres" means "not later than at the beginning" of a year because there simply is nothing in a year earlier than its beginning.

Comment: @user44591 I read that sentence as saying that enrollment is indeed limited to the beginning of the year.

Comment: @user44591 No, your example means that enrollment is only possible during a short period of time at the beginning of each year.

Comment: @DonHolgo I see what you mean, but to me that part of your answer is confusing. I would delete it.

Comment: I am satisfied that the usage is, to some extent, vague. "not at any other time" is a point in time that occurs in both time periods, "not earlier than" and "not later than", making the usage, at times, confusing. Thank you for the discussion.